# Multi User Photo Blog

Tags: blog, photos

I am looking for an open source web app like pixelpost with multi user support.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just about any general-use blogging software will probably meet your needs. I have the most experience with [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/). It has multi user support, and there are many themes available that are optimized for photo blogs.